# Rotating label in BarChart

Tags: graphics, labeling, charts

I have created a bar chart, but I have some issues with the labeling of the sample in X-axis. 
May I seek help to find out how can I rotate the label in the X-axis direction.  Appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
JoinData =  Join[{Data5s1A, Data5s2A, Data5s3A, Data5s1B, Data5s2B, Data5s3B,Data7s1A, Data7s2A, Data7s1B, Data7s2B, Data10Ys1A, Data10Ys2A,Data10Ys3A, Data10Ys1B, Data10Ys2B, Data10Ys3B, Data10Xs1A,Data10Ys3A, Data10Ys1B, Data10Ys2B, Data10Ys3B, Data10Xs1A, Data10Xs2A, Data10Xs3A, Data10Xs1B, Data10Xs2B, Data10Xs3B,Data20Ys1A, Data20Ys2A, Data20Ys1B, Data20Ys2B, Data20Xs1A, Data20Xs2A, Data20Xs1B, Data20Xs2B, Data27s1A, Data27s2A,Data27s3A, Data27s1B, Data27s2B, Data27s3B, Data30s1A, Data30s2A,Data30s3A, Data30s1B, Data30s2B, Data30s3B}]

{0.00966667, 0.00216667, -0.001, 0.0215, 0.0116667, 0.0228333, 0.005, -0.00333333, 0.015, 0.01, 0.015, 0.025, 0.0266667, 1/30, 0.0266667, 0.0266667, 0.0233333, 0.00166667, 0.00333333, 0.03, 0.0183333, 0.0116667, 0.08, 0.0833333, 0.0266667, 0.0516667, 0.0516667, 0.0333333, 0.005, 0.0116667, 0.055, 0.04, 0.0116667, 0.0383333, 0.08, 0.0233333, 0.045, 0.103333, 0.11, 0.04, 0.16, 0.0716667}

label = {"5 S1A", "5 S2A", "5 S3A", "5 S1B", "5 S2B", "5 S3B","7 S1A", "7 S2A", "7 S1B", "7 S2B", "10YS1A", "10YS2A", "10YS3A","10YS1B", "10YS2B", "10Y3B", "10XS1A", "10XS2A", "10XS3A","10XS1B", "10XS2B", "10X3B", "20YS1A", "20YS2A", "20YS1B","20YS2B", "20XS1A", "20XS2A", "20XS1B", "20XS2B", "27 S1A","27 S2A", "27 S3A", "27 S1B", "27 S2B", "27 S3B", "30 S1A","30 S2A", "30 S3A", "30 S1B", "30 S2B", "30 S3B"};

BarChart[{JoinData}, PlotLabel -> "Overall", 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "\[CapitalDelta]k\[CapitalOmega]/n"}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[label, Axis], Frame -> All, 
 PlotRange -> {-0.05, 0.2}]
```

Comment: junliang04, just noticed that  you have not accepted any answers to you questions and your profile says  "This user has not cast any [votes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)" although you have been a member for more than a year. Please consider voting for answers and questions that you find useful.

Comment: Hi Kglr, May i ask how can i cast the vote?

Comment: Hi ljsg, Our standard welcome message: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the third argument of `Placed` to rotate the labels,

```
ChartLabels -> Placed[label, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]
```

we get

[image]

You get the same result by wrapping each label with `Rotate[#, 90 Degree]`, that is, using

```
ChartLabels -> Placed[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ label, Axis]
```

gives the same output as above.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve the same results without separately setting the `label` variable, similarly to  `ChartLabels -> Automatic` ?

Comment: @alancalvitti, not sure i understand; you mean to get the labels (in some way) from the input data?

Comment: Right, why should users have to specify the list of labels when `Automatic` can reference them? Why can't the options be: `ChartLabels->Automatic, Rotate-> 90 Degree`?